# What important contemporary philosophers are engaged in a critique of technology, and how?

Tags: philosophy-of-technology, contemporary-philosophy

What important contemporary philosophers are engaged in a critique of technology, and how? I'm interested in reading the best of these, and an outline would help me decide who to read.

I'm asking because, given that there will be no world wars, and / or the status of communism, what the limits of technology should be, and what its effects are, seems to be the most pressing (Existing) problem for humanity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an entire subfield of [Philosophy of Technology](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/technology/).  For your specific question, you might be especially interested in the work of [Langdon Winner](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=langdon+winner) and Shannon Vallor's new book [*Technology and the Virtues*](https://books.google.com/books?id=D3PADAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=shannon+vallor,+technology+and+the+virtues&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj-rvqzmu_WAhWG8YMKHf6zD3EQ6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q=shannon%20vallor%2C%20technology%20and%20the%20virtues&f=false).

Comment: not a very inspiring or thorough answer, but thanks

Comment: would work as a comment. as it stands you sound patronising, and given you've read the books you're recommending, unhelpful

Comment: @user3293056: given that you've provided very little or no background in your question your two comments comes across as rather condescending.

Comment: @user3293056: and what's wrong with recommending books that one has read? Would you prefer he had recommended books that he hasn't read?

Comment: @MoziburUllah nothing wrong with any of it, i'm just saying that, whatever you think of @ Dan the answer is a little unhelpful. i mean, this isn't anything to do with what i think of @ Dan, only the question

Comment: i mean, tonally, starting such a rushed answer with "there's an entire subfield" does seem somewhat patronising (i mean overly so). but that's not really what i was frustrated about. and now i'm disappointed that my comment, meant for the good of the site, really, has met such resistance. however, i can always read the book reviews if i really cared (i don't really now!)